# Identifying clusters with OPTICS in R

Tags: r, clustering, dbscan

I am experimenting with OPTICS clustering in R and from what I have seen in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbscan/vignettes/dbscan.pdf) the valleys and peaks somehow determine the number of clusters which than can be extracted using `extractDBSCAN` and `extractXi`. I tried to do clustering on a dataset with 10 features (with `minPts = 11`) and got the following plot. Could someone help me with it's interpretation, as I do not see any pattern similar to the one in the vignette. [image]

Answer (score 1):

A shape like this indicates that you have some density peaks (these are easy to spot...). But you don't appear to have *larger areas* of similar high density, which would cause wider valleys.

Whether or not these narrow density peaks are to be considered clusters depends on your data and task.

Comment: Could you give an example when it would be sufficient to form cluster on this basis? I am doing some customer segmentation with multiple features per client.